# ASP.NET Api RequestQueue Spikes

Tags: asp.net, iis

I have a c# asp.net application API running where 1-2k requests per second is what I call "normal traffic" which usually works well.

The api is hosted in a 16 core server, with 64GB of ram.

Somehow it looks like the ASP.NET is parsing/handling the requests in batches, or taking short breaks somehow.

As you can see in the Graph Below, cpu is never really above 40%. The other thing is that when it stats queuing up the requests, the cpu goes down, and then peaks when going through the queue:
[image: CPU vs Queued Requests Graph]

The Red Line is cpu (%), and the green line is x10 requests queued.
I have tried to fine-tune the max worker threads per cpu with no success, as well as maxConcurrentRequestsPerCPU and many other related settings.

What else could be limiting, or causing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Much requests, so spiky

Comment: @sh1rts such fix, very fast

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not know, but there is a MaxWorkerProcesses in the application pool settings. That solved the spiking.